# The 'INSERT' command is denied to the user: '' @ '@ localhost' on the 'prposutionl' table

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

Hello everyone there's almost **2 days** that I remain stagnant at the level of this error, I tried several solutions published on the forums but it did not work if someone can help me to move forward.

I would Thank you.

> Erreur SQL: INSERT INTO covoiturage.proposition ( pointdepart, pointarrivee, date, horaire, type, nbrdeplace, prix, numero, description) VALUES ('Bab bhar','CitÃ© el Khadhra','2018-01-30','22:06','e','2','7.1','21625822649','At Vous pouvez dÃ©crire le trajet que vous proposee ainsi que ses options en dÃ©tail :)! ') --- La commande 'INSERT' est interdite à l'utilisateur: ''@'@localhost' sur la table 'proposition'

Comment: you need to GRANT those permissions

Comment: the error seems self explanatory. This development or production environment?

Comment: @Akintunde007 the development environement

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner and how  to fix it?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for you reponse I tried this but it didnt work this is my code      GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' ...

Comment: according to the error the user in question is not root. Have you truncated the error though - not sure you can have a user just called `@`? root already has all privileges in any case, so doesn't need anything granting. And to be clear, your application should absolutely NOT be logging into the mysql server as root, it's just asking to be hacked. Doesn't sound like you're doing that, but just worth mentioning.

Comment: yes @ADyson  I tried with @ also but it dosn't work :/

Comment: Your user is just called @ and nothing else?? Maybe pick a better name

Answer (score 0):

If you login to MySQl correctly the import will work.

Login to phpMyAdmin using the Super User account and it can do anything so when you see the phpMyAdmin login screen use these credentials

```
Username = root
Password = nothing (leave it blank)
```

Comment: thanks for your reponse but I am already logged in with root: /

Comment: Sure you didn't mess up the root account when you attempted to add privilages it already had??